# Hadoop MapReduce Job Hangs

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I am trying to simulate the Hadoop environment using latest Hadoop version 2.6.0, Java SDK 1.70 on my Ubuntu desktop.  I configured the hadoop with necessary environment parameters and all its processes are up and running and they can be seen with the following jps command:

```
nandu@nandu-Desktop:~$ jps
2810 NameNode
3149 SecondaryNameNode
3416 NodeManager
3292 ResourceManager
2966 DataNode
4805 Jps
```

I could also see the above information, plus the dfs files through the Firefox browser.  However, when I tried to run a simple WordCound MapReduce job, it hangs and it doesn't produce any output or shows any error message(s).  After a while I killed the process using the "hadoop job -kill " command.  Can you please guide me, to find the cause of this issue and how to resolve it?  I am giving below the Job start and kill(end) screenshot.

If you need additional information, please let me know.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

```
===================================================================
nandu@nandu-Desktop:~/dev$ hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/nandu/input /user/nandu/output
15/02/27 10:35:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/02/27 10:35:20 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/02/27 10:35:21 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
15/02/27 10:35:21 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
15/02/27 10:35:21 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
15/02/27 10:35:22 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1425048764581_0003
15/02/27 10:35:22 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1425048764581_0003
15/02/27 10:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://nandu-Desktop:8088/proxy/application_1425048764581_0003/
15/02/27 10:35:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1425048764581_0003

==================== at this point the job was killed ===================

15/02/27 10:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1425048764581_0003 running in uber mode : false
15/02/27 10:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/02/27 10:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1425048764581_0003 failed with state KILLED due to: Application killed by user.
15/02/27 10:38:23 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
```

Comment: I figured, why this job was hanging - the mapreduce process did not have enough space to run successfully. I cleaned a few directories by removing unnecessary big (.gz) files, that made enough space for mapreduce to run.  If you are in similar situation, make sure you have enough disk space, so that it wont hang.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar problem while running provided `MapReduce` sample in hadoop package. In my case it was hanging due to low disk space on my VM (about 1.5 GB was empty). When I freed some disk space it ran pretty fine. Also, please check other system resource requirements are fulfilled.